# How do I make boxes with the same number of pixels of height actually render to the same height even with different top locations?

Tags: html, css

I am making a graph with lines made out of divs that have a height specified to 2px. The location of the lines (specified via margin-top) changes based on the data. Even though all of the divs have the same height (2px) they look like they are different heights visually. How can I make them all look like the same height?

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.dataPointGraph {
  background-color: #e5f8e9;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  height: 3em;
}

.dataPointLine {
  background-color: #28a745;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="dataPointGraph">
    <div class="dataPointLine" style="margin-top: 1px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dataPointGraph">
    <div class="dataPointLine" style="margin-top: 2px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dataPointGraph">
    <div class="dataPointLine" style="margin-top: 3px"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dataPointGraph">
    <div class="dataPointLine" style="margin-top: 4px"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see the issue on Chrome and Firefox on https://www.pinging.net. I see different heights for the default zoom but if I use a browser Zoom greater than 100% the differences will eventually go away. I believe its caused by sub pixel rendering but I am unsure how to change the behavior. Any suggestions on how to ensure the same height at the default zoom level?

Comment: What is the purpose of the inline styles `style="margin-top: 1px"`, removing this from each `dataPointLine` will fix it.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the system struggling to work out exactly how to map CSS pixels to screen pixels (several screen pixels will be used for 1 CSS pixel on modern devices). For example, if you zoom in you'll probably see the lines looking the same some of the time.

Comment: @aabdulahad On the actual site (pinging.net) the lines are supposed to be at different heights to represent different amounts of latency.

Comment: @AHaworth Agreed. I am hoping there is a way to tweak things so the renderer knows to prioritize the consistency of the heights of the lines (and perhaps sacrifice accuracy on the position instead).